# AngularJs Bootstrap components in Electron application are flickering in compiled builds

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, electron

I have an AngularJs application that uses Bootstrap v3.3.7. I have wrapped the application in Electron so it is a desktop application. When I am in my development environment, I do not have this problem. But when I compile the application and it is in production, this problem occurs. The problem is when moving the mouse across the application, the colors of the styling on different components will flicker different blocky shades of dark gray. The mouse doesn't even need to hover over anything for the blocky flickering to happen. I have seen it most on my bootstrap panels in my application. Here is an image as an example:

[image: Weird blocky flickering shadows]